# Premier pro flips the order of srt letters

Tags: caption, adobe-premiere

I imported an srt file to premier pro cc 2015 but the order of the letters fliped. 
the captions are in Hebrew.
Does anyone know how to reflip it?

Answer (score 0):

Once the captions are in your timeline, you can add "flip vertical" and/or "flip horizontal" effects depending on the orientation of your text. If you flip vertically, you will have to change the Y-location of your titles. Enable title-safe in your video preview and line the bottom of the your widest title up with that line. This will get you close to the location of where your captions were before.